# Using "program_name_transform" from autoconf in program

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

In my project that uses autoconf and automake, I have two executables, say "foo" and "bar".  Suppose "foo.c" looks like

```
int main()
{
    exec ("bar");
    return 0;
}
```

I.e., "foo" uses "bar".  This works fine once I do`./configure && make && make install`. However, the autoconf provides an option to transform program names.  For example, I could do `./configure --program-suffix=-2.0`.  Then "foo" and "bar" will be installed instead as

```
/usr/bin/foo-2.0
/usr/bin/bar-2.0
```

In that case, the reference to "bar" inside "foo" would be incorrect, because there will be no `bar` in the system (should be `bar-2.0`).  Is there any way I can let autoconf/automake adjust this reference automatically?

Comment: Especially if the transformation is for different version numbers, wouldn't it be better to augment your `make install` with a command to symlink `bar -> bar-2.0`?

Comment: That may work in some cases. But if multiple versions are to coexist, then it will not work. You will have `bar-2.0` and `bar-3.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Makefile` you may run the `$(program_transform_name)` sed script to create a header file with the final names.

For instance, assuming your program names are `foo` and `bar`, create a `names.h.in` file containing:

```
#define FOO_NAME "@foo-name@"
#define BAR_NAME "@bar-name@"
```

Then equip your `Makefile.am` to have rules to generate `names.h` from `names.h.in`:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = names.h
EXTRA_DIST = names.h.in

edit = sed \
  -e 's/@foo-name@/'`echo foo | sed '$(program_transform_name)'`'/g;' \
  -e 's/@bar-name@/'`echo bar | sed '$(program_transform_name)'`'/g;'

names.h: $(srcdir)/names.h.in Makefile
        $(edit) < $(srcdir)/names.h.in > $@
```

and finally include `names.h` and use `FOO_NAME` and `BAR_NAME` in your source code.

Comment: This works!  One tiny problem however: I can no longer run the program inside the build directory since `fool` would look for `bar-2.0` instead, which will not exist until the installation time.  Is there any way around?

Comment: When a program calls other programs, I think it should always have some setting (an option, an environment variable, or a config file) to override these program names at runtime.  You would typically use such setting in your test suite to ensure that the local version of the binary are called during `make check`.